# Not Found 404 error after file upload using store() in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I have uploaded an image using the following code in Laravel 5.8 **Image upload is working fine**. But it gives a 404 error when I try to display it.

```
public function store(ImageUpload $request)
{    
    $path = $request->file('image')->store('public/user_images');
    echo "<img src='" . $path . "'>";
}
```

I also tried `<img src=".asset($path).">` It also gives a 404 Not Found error. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: What is the output of `$path`

Comment: @ascsoftw $path is `public/user_images/TTsmQg6yp4dG8XZzXE8leTU9Z0VTXamVgbfoNWkT.jpeg`

Comment: Try removing 'public' from the $path

Comment: @ascsoftw I tried that. Still same 404 error. I also did `php artisan storage:link` as per Laravel doc. Still same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the url with

```
Storage::url($path);
```

The `$path` returned is actually the path on the server inside storage and not the URL of the file.

With `storage:link` you're basically linking from `http://url.dev/storage/` to `/storage/public`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#file-urls

Comment: I got the following value for $url:

`/storage/user_images/EtSDpLgG8BciZYcwxVCdmGlmJGmAqWNREJPNR91v.jpeg`

Still 404 error.

I am using Homestead. Is there anything I should do with routes or something like that?

Comment: same error after make a copy paste of the proyect in another folder.. I make storage link but I can't see my files in the browser.. the file was uploaded ok